# Passing callbacks with args down component hierarchy in react.js

Tags: javascript, callback, reactjs

I am using react.js in my project and I have component hierarchy like this.

```
RootComponent
|- Child1
|  |- itemA1
|  |- itemA2
|   - ...
 - Child2
   |- itemB1
   |- itemB2
    _ ...
```

I have all the state in RootComponent, which is:

- array of itemA elements
- array of itemB elements
- index of currently selected itemA
- index of currently selected itemB

I want to change the currently selected item by clicking on an item, so I created a property in my RootComponent:

```
changeCurrentItemA: function(item) {
    console.log("check, if the function was called");
    //do something with state
}
```

I passed it down to `Child1`:

```
<Child1 items={this.state.data.itemsA} changeCurrentItemA={this.changeCurrentItemA} />
```

In the child compomnent, I take the function from props:

```
var changeCurrentItemA = this.props.changeCurrentItemA;
```

and I wanted to render it like this:

```
<li onClick={changeCurrentItemA(item)} />
```

This howerver immediately evaluates the function, so during rendering, it gets evaluated n times and nothing happens, when I click it.

How can I tell react to run function with variable `item` passed to it after user clicks.

I saw similar question here: [React.js how to pass callbacks to child components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909171/react-js-how-to-pass-callbacks-to-child-components)
but the function there has no arguments.

EDIT:
It is not a duplicate of questions about `bind`, because react hijacks default `bind` behaviour allowing only binding on components.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a problem. I could call `bind` in the scope of `Child1` component to provide `item` as an argument, however, I would also have to provide `this`. Should I also pass "this value of `RootComponent`" down to the `Child1` to be able to call `bind` in `Child1` or is there better solution?

Comment: Try `onClick={this.props.changeCurrentItemA.bind(this, item)}`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have to refresh my understanding on this and bind in javascript.