# Callback Function With Parameters ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working with ReactJS and having trouble understanding how `callback functions` work with ReactJS.

I have a parent component titled `TodoFormComponent`, which initializes my list of todo items. I've created a callback function on the `TodoItemsComonent`, but it doesn't trigger the `updateItem` method and display the `selected` item.

> **Question:** How can I pass data from the child to the parent? I want to pass the selected todo item to the parent so that I can update the master todo list.

---

**Parent Component (TodoFormComponent)**

---

The `TodoFormComponent` has `selectedTask`, which should be triggering the `updateItem` method.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TodoItemsComponent from "../todo-items/todo-items.component";
import AddTodoItemComponent from "../add-todo-item/add-todo-item.component";

export default class TodoFormComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            todoItems: [
                { id: '1', todo: 'First Todo Item' },
                { id: '2', todo: 'Second Todo Item' },
                { id: '3', todo: 'Third Todo Item' }
            ],
            selected: {}
        };

        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
    }

    updateItem () {
        console.log('Selected Value:: ', this.state.selected);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="well col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                        <h1>To do: </h1>
                        <div name="todo-items">
                            <TodoItemsComponent items={this.state.todoItems} selectedTask={() => {this.updateItem}}/>
                        </div>
                        <div name="add-todo-item">
                            <AddTodoItemComponent/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

**Child Component (TodoItemsComponent)**

---

The `TodoItemsComponent` has an `onClick` to update the selected value. This gets updated in the `selectedTask` function.
    import * as React from "react";

```
export default class TodoItemsComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    selectedTask (item) {
        this.setState({selected: item})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group">
                {
                    this.props.items.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <li className="list-group-item">
                                {item.todo}
                                <div className="pull-right">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-xs btn-success">
                                        &#x2713;
                                    </button> <button
                                        type="button"
                                        className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                                        onClick={() => {this.selectedTask(item)}}
                                        >&#xff38;
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever you want to pass data from child to parent you pass a function as a prop to child and from child you call that function using `this.props.passedFunction(yourDataToPassToParent)`

Here from your parent component you are passing the `selectedTask` function as prop, so you should call `this.prop.selectedTask()` with the data to be passed to parent like:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
  onClick={() => {this.props.selectedTask(item)}}
 >
  &#xff38;
 </button>
```

Also the way you are passing the `selectedTask` in your parent is wrong. You should pass it like this:

```
<TodoItemsComponent items={this.state.todoItems} selectedTask={this.updateItem}/>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you're the man! :) This did the trick... I was trying to do the lambda function on the parent, which was preventing it from triggering my method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your TodoItemsComponent,updateItem() is passed as prop. So you need to call the `this.props.updateItem()`in your onClick method.

So your button should be:

```
                 <button
                 type="button"
                 className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                 onClick={() => 
                     {this.props.selectedTask(item)}}>&#xff38;
                 </button>
```

and Update your parent components UpdateItem method to receive properties as item. Like this:

```
updateItem (e) {
    console.log('Selected Value:: ', e);
}
```

And to pass method in children you need to

```
             <TodoItemsComponent items=
                 {this.state.todoItems} selectedTask={this.updateItem}/>
```

If you do this: `{()=>this.updateItem()}` then it will initialize the method. So you need just pass the function reference.

Comment: I updated the child component, but this still doesn't trigger my parent component method, `updateItem`. Any other ideas?

Comment: change this in your parent component <TodoItemsComponent items={this.state.todoItems} selectedTask={this.updateItem}/>

Answer (score 1):

## fixed code:

```js
class TodoItemsComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group">
        {this.props.items.map(item => {
          return (
            <li className="list-group-item">
              {item.todo}
              <div className="pull-right">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-xs btn-success">
                  &#x2713;
                </button>{" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-xs btn-danger"
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.props.selectedTask(item);
                  }}
                >
                  &#xff38;
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class TodoFormComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todoItems: [
        { id: "1", todo: "First Todo Item" },
        { id: "2", todo: "Second Todo Item" },
        { id: "3", todo: "Third Todo Item" }
      ],
      selected: {}
    };

    this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
  }

  updateItem(item) {
    this.setState({ selected: item });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="well col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
            <h1>To do: </h1>
            <h3>
              Selected task: {JSON.stringify(this.state.selected)}
            </h3>
            <div name="todo-items">
              <TodoItemsComponent
                items={this.state.todoItems}
                selectedTask={this.updateItem}
              />
            </div>
            <div name="add-todo-item" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => <TodoFormComponent />;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/LgrGKK9og

Answer (score 0):

You have to send updateItem as a prop to the child Component.

```
const Parent = () => 
<div>
  <TodoItemsComponent items={this.state.todoItems} selectedTask={updateItem}/>
</div>
```

Also update

```
updateItem (item) {  
   this.setState({ selected: item })
   console.log( 'Selected Value:: ', item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Child id={1} onClick={(id) => console.log(id)}/>);
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.id)}></div>);
    }
}
```

Console.log will output "1"

More: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909171/react-js-how-to-pass-callbacks-to-child-components)