# Passing props to handler function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following [Pure React](https://daveceddia.com/pure-react/), and there's a `House` component that needs some building (omitted the imports for brevity):

```js
class House extends React.Component {

    state = {
        bathroom: true,
        bedroom: false,
        kitchen: true,
        livingRoom: false
    }

    flipSwitch = (action) => {
        this.setState({
            ???????????????
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <>
            <RoomButton room='kitchen' handler={this.flipSwitch}/>
            <RoomButton room='bathroom' handler={this.flipSwitch}/>
            <RoomButton room='livingRoom' handler={this.flipSwitch}/>
            <RoomButton room='bedroom' handler={this.flipSwitch}/>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const RoomButton = ({room, handler}) => (
    <button onClick={handler}>
        {`Flip light in ${room}!`}
    </button>
)

ReactDOM.render (
    <House/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Desired outcome: when you click the `<room>` button, the state of the `House` component changes to reflect the flipping of the lightswitch in the room (i.e. true is light on, false is light off).

I'm wondering what should go instead of the `?????`  - how do I pass the `room` prop into the `handler` function from inside a given `RoomButton` component?

Tried just passing it in, and got a `Maximum depth reached` error from React.

ES6 answers would be most appreciated, BTW.

Comment: Presumably the error was because you wrote `handler={this.flipSwitch("kitchen")}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep! I figured it was some sort of (React's version) of a stack overflow (hehe), but wasn't really sure how to decipher it and come up with an actionable solution.

Comment: Then it's because you're calling the function and passing the *result* as the handler. You need to "defer execution", note that you didn't start with `handler={this.flipSwitch()}`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback Function With Parameters ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359113/callback-function-with-parameters-reactjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this solution :

the `flipSwitch` will accept the room name as parameter and will update the state using a callback (in order to retrieve the right value of the current state)

```
 class House extends React.component {
 ....

   flipSwitch = room => {
     this.setState(state => ({
        [room]: !state[room]
     });
   }

 ...
 }


const RoomButton = ({room, handler}) => (
  <button onClick={() => handler(room)}>
    {`Flip light in ${room}!`}
  </button>
);
```

Comment: Olivier - so you pass an anonymous arrow function? Not sure I see how this works.

Comment: yes it's simply a function. In the accepted answer it uses `bind` which actually also create a function

Comment: In a world where arrow functions are available, I'd use them over `.bind` as it way clearer what the intent is and there is no risk to mess up the context that way.

Comment: yes I think this answer is better than the accepted one, in addition to that its preferable to use a callback in `setState` when the next state value depends of the current state otherwise if you click really fase twice on the same button, you could have an undesirable behavior as `setState` is asynchronous

Comment: _"its preferable to use a callback in `setState`"_ It really depends on what's the expected behaviour. Say OP only wants it to switch once even if called multiple times, then a shallow merged object would be ok. But it's definitely good to be aware of the side-effects of both techniques!

Comment: This is the more idiomatic way to do it in React, as far as I've seen. The `bind` way still works fine though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
flipSwitch = (room, action) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        [room]: !prevState[room]
    }));
}

const RoomButton = ({room, handler}) => (
    <button onClick={handler.bind(null, room)}>
        {`Flip light in ${room}!`}
    </button>
)
```

The `.bind(null, room)` line essentially preloads the handler function with one of the arguments, in this case room. This is called currying. I left action in the `flipSwitch` parameters list in case you had plans for it, but it's unused currently.

Comment: You're missing the square brackets `[room]:` and now the `action` variable is useless. But otherwise, this is correct.

Comment: @JeffHechler Ah! Yes, I've tried this but totally forgot to bind `room` to the handler. Why the `null` there, though?

Comment: you dont want to change the context of the function. `this.setState` would be undefined if you changed that null to this. Essentially it means dont touch the `this` context of that function.

Comment: the null argument is in the place of `this`, preventing a replacement of the `this` keyword's context. By passing in null, the context is preserved.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks a bunch to all three of you!

Comment: @john flipSwitch is an arrow function, so the context does't change with bind.

Comment: When using `.bind` or `.apply` on an arrow function, the first argument (the context) is completely irrelevant. You could pass anything and it would still work with the right `this.setState`.